# Using fgets to read and print multiple lines from .txt file

Tags: c, arrays, file, char, fgets

```
FILE *fp = fopen("story.txt", "r");
if(fp == NULL){
    printf("\nError opening file.\nExiting program.\n");
    exit(1);
}
char text[100];

while(fgets(text, 100, fp) != NULL){
    printf("%s", text);
}
printf("\n");
fclose(fp);
```

I'm trying to print the first 100 characters of a text file, including new lines, however when I use the code above it presents some weird behavior. First of all, it only prints the very last line of the text file, which itself is under 100 characters. Also, if I include two print statements in the while loop i.e.

```
while(fgets(text, 100, fp) != NULL){
   printf("%s", text);
   printf("%s", text);
```

}

It prints a lot more than 125 chars of the text file (somewhere in the thousands, it's a big text file), and the contents of said text is a bunch of seemingly random segments from the file in one constant stream, no new lines or anything.

So I guess my question is is there any way to use fgets so that it prints the text in the file, starting from the top, and includes new lines? I eventually have to use this to turn a text file into a character array, so that I can make a new, modified character array based off of that array, which will be printed to a new text file. So if there is a better way to approach that end goal, that would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** after some discussion in the comments I've realized that the text I am using is just one big block of text with carriage returns and no newlines. I guess at this point my main problem is how to turn this text file with carriage returns into a character array.

Comment: How long are the lines in the text file?

Comment: I suspect that your lines are much longer than 100 characters, so there is no newline present in `text` most of the time. You might try adding `fflush(stdout);` after the call to `printf()`.

Comment: Seems thatthe lines are under 100 characters, and the segments of those lines that are printing are under 100 characters. All around the current output had a lot of really weird behavior. For example, when I include two prinf statements and resize the terminal to what seems to be a width of over 100 results in printing out of only the last line of the text file, along with some extra seemingly random words from near the end of the text. However, when the terminal is resized to something smaller, it prints out much much more text. Something similar happens when only one printf statement is used

Comment: The code you posted seems fine; I tested it on a text file to be sure. Post working code that compiles and a short sample of text that will reproduce the behavior that you observe. BTW, line lengths are determined by newlines, and for a file called `"story.txt"`, I expect newlines only every paragraph, so I expect lines longer than 100 characters. Is this not correct?

Comment: I tested my code on a sample text file where all the lines are for sure under 100 characters, and it worked perfectly. I would expect you are right about the newlines every paragraph thing, I must have missed it because my text editor showing the text as if there are new lines (EDIT: I just opened it in Vim and it showed no new lines, I'm not sure why Gedit was not showing the same.). To fix this, would I just have to increase the size from 100 to something larger?

Comment: Okay so apparently the text is filled with carriage returns, not newlines. I'm not really sure how to deal with this. I'm guessing I would have to parse through the entire thing and print a new line every time there's a carriage return? Could I still use the same approach with fgets?

Comment: If you are using Linux, you could use `tr` to replace the carriage returns with newlines: `tr '\r' '\n' < story.txt > story_mod.txt`.

Comment: Could what I'm trying to achieve be done without changing the carriage returns to newlines? The text file uses ^M carriage returns, would `tr '^M' '\n' < story.txt > story_mod.txt work?

Comment: I think that Vim is just printing **^M** for CRs; either `tr '\r' '\n' < story.txt > story_mod.txt` or `sed 's/\r/\n/g' story.txt > story_mod.txt` should work.

Comment: Thanks, the CTRL-V CTRL-M thing worked It is now printing as it should. However now I have to deal with the problem of modifying this text and writing it to another text file. Would it be wiser to put the entire file's contents into a character array, and use that array to be a point of reference for a new array with modifications that will be written to a file (my original plan), or do it line by line, such as in my fgets while loop, writing a new, modified line to a text file while parsing through each new line in the original file? Sorry if this doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I am not _entirely_ clear on your goal, but it sounds like you could read a line of text at a time with `fgets()`, and remove any carriage returns or newlines so that you have only an array of strings representing the text file.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to read a text file in lines of 100 characters, and to do away with the carriage returns, you can still use `fgets()` as long as you remember that `fgets()` will take characters up to and including the next newline, or until one less than the specified number of characters has been read.

The code below reads a line of text, up to `BUFFER_SZ-1` characters, increases the memory allocation to hold a new line of text, and copies the line into the allocated space, removing carriage returns and any trailing newlines. Note that the address of the reallocated space is first stored in a temporary pointer. `realloc()` returns a null pointer in the event of an allocation error, and this step avoids a potential memory leak.

Since the lines are broken at `BUFFER_SZ-1` characters, words may be split across lines, and you may want to develop additional logic to handle this. It would be more efficient to reallocate in larger chunks and less frequently, rather than once for every line, as is done here. Also note that it may be useful to open the file in binary mode to more closely parse line endings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFER_SZ 100

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("story.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char buffer[BUFFER_SZ];
    char (*text)[sizeof buffer] = NULL;
    char (*temp)[sizeof buffer] = NULL;
    size_t numlines = 0;

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp) != NULL) {
        ++numlines;
        /* Allocate space for next line */
        temp = realloc(text, sizeof(*text) * numlines);
        if (temp == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error in realloc()\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        text = temp;

        /* Copy buffer to text, removing carriage returns and newlines */
        char *c = buffer;
        char *line = text[numlines-1];
        while (*c != '\n' && *c != '\0') {
            if (*c != '\r') {
                *line++ = *c;
            }
            ++c;
        }
        *c = '\0';
    }

    if (fclose(fp) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to close file\n");
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < numlines; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", text[i]);
    }

    free(text);

    return 0;
}
```

Another option would be to replace the carriage returns with newlines. This may be what OP had in mind. The above program is easily modified to accomplish this. Note that the `\n` is removed from the `printf()` statement that displays the results, since newlines are now included in the strings.

```
...

    /* Copy buffer to text, converting carriage returns to newlines */
    char *c = buffer;
    char *line = text[numlines-1];
    while (*c != '\n' && *c != '\0') {
        if (*c == '\r') {
            *line++ = '\n';
        } else {
            *line++ = *c;
        }
        ++c;
    }
    *c = '\0';
}

if (fclose(fp) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to close file\n");
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < numlines; i++) {
    printf("%s", text[i]);
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't copy one line onto the end of another. It simply reuses the buffer you keep passing it. If you want multiple lines stored, copy them to another buffer, and concatenate them. (See: strcat)